# When one approximates a matrix A with a sequence A_n, does this necessarily mean the sequence converges to A?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, convergence-divergence, proof-explanation

When one approximates a matrix with a sequence of matrices, does this usually imply that the sequence converges?

Thanks,

Comment: Well, if the sequence does not converge, then it wouldn't be a very good approximation. Generally, approximating means getting arbitrarily close, so such a sequence would be constructed to converge.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks so much @user332239 :)